# reconnecting-websocket.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: django, django-models, websocket, django-views

I tried deploy my Django channels with WebSocket on Nginx, I tried a lot of ways but all failed try to change on my Nginx and tried to change the WebSocket URL but there is no any way work with me

My nginx

```
  location /ws/ {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

my websocket url

```
    var wsStart = 'ws://'
if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname
var socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(endpoint)
```

my django channel layer in settings

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
    'CONFIG': {
        'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],
    },
},
```

}

Comment: How are you starting your Django instance?

Comment: Hello can you clarify what mean of starting Django instance?

Comment: What are you executing to get your Django application up?

Comment: By gunicorn and nginx

Comment: Please share the exact command you're using to start the gunicorn.

Comment: Actually, I followed video to deploy my website, but I use this code to restart my gunicorn, `service gunicorn restart`

Comment: Can you please share that tutorial and any modifications you've made to the steps described in it?

Comment: Of Curse, [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14zdpWW6eqw&t=2549s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14zdpWW6eqw&t=2549s)

Comment: Have you configured Daphne server as well?

Comment: Yes and I check the status of Daphne and it working

Comment: Please make sure you're restarting Daphne too after making changes in the code.